# How to Assign Data after Groupby and Concat in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, concatenation

Iam newbie in python. I have huge a `dataframe` with millions of rows and id. my data looks like this:

```
Time    ID  X   Y
8:00    A   23  100
9:00    B   24  110
10:00   B   25  120
11:00   C   26  130
12:00   C   27  140
13:00   A   28  150
14:00   A   29  160
15:00   D   30  170
16:00   C   31  180
17:00   B   32  190
18:00   A   33  200
19:00   C   34  210
20:00   A   35  220
21:00   B   36  230
22:00   C   37  240
23:00   B   38  250
```

I sorted the data on id and time.

```
Time    ID  X   Y
8:00    A   23  100
13:00   A   28  150
14:00   A   29  160
18:00   A   33  200
20:00   A   35  220
9:00    B   24  110
10:00   B   25  120
17:00   B   32  190
21:00   B   36  230
23:00   B   38  250
11:00   C   26  130
12:00   C   27  140
16:00   C   31  180
19:00   C   34  210
22:00   C   37  240
15:00   D   30  170
```

and I want to pick only "The first and the last" of the id and eliminate the rest. The result looked like this:

```
Time    ID  X   Y
8:00    A   23  100
20:00   A   35  220
9:00    B   24  110
23:00   B   38  250
11:00   C   26  130
22:00   C   37  240
15:00   D   30  170
```

I used this code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
g = df.groupby('ID')
g_1 = pd.concat([g.head(1),g.tail(1)]).drop_duplicates().sort_values('ID').reset_index(drop=True)
g_1.to_csv('result.csv')
```

but I want to assign or give annotation every row as "first" and "last" in the new column.
my expected result looks like this:

```
Time    ID  X   Y   Annotation
8:00    A   23  100 First
20:00   A   35  220 Last
9:00    B   24  110 First
23:00   B   38  250 Last
11:00   C   26  130 First
22:00   C   37  240 Last
15:00   D   30  170
```

anyone could help me with this? please give me advice thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use groupby agg,first and last. Works perfectly for the column Annotation. As a bonus, this will work on the original dataframe so no need to sort

```
df3.groupby('ID').agg(['first', 'last']).stack().reset_index().rename(columns = {'level_1': 'Annotation'})

    ID  Annotation  Time    X   Y
0   A   first   8:00    23  100
1   A   last    20:00   35  220
2   B   first   9:00    24  110
3   B   last    23:00   38  250
4   C   first   11:00   26  130
5   C   last    22:00   37  240
6   D   first   15:00   30  170
7   D   last    15:00   30  170
```

Answer (score 3):

No need `groupby` using `drop_duplicates`after you sort

```
df=pd.concat([df.drop_duplicates(['ID']).assign(sign='first'),df.drop_duplicates(['ID'],keep='last').assign(sign='last')]).sort_values('ID')
df
     Time ID   X    Y   sign
0    8:00  A  23  100  first
4   20:00  A  35  220   last
5    9:00  B  24  110  first
9   23:00  B  38  250   last
10  11:00  C  26  130  first
14  22:00  C  37  240   last
15  15:00  D  30  170  first
15  15:00  D  30  170   last
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df.groupby('ID').agg(['first','last'])\
  .stack(1).reset_index()\
  .rename(columns={'level_1':'Annotation'})
```

Output:

```
  ID Annotation   Time   X    Y
0  A      first   8:00  23  100
1  A       last  20:00  35  220
2  B      first   9:00  24  110
3  B       last  23:00  38  250
4  C      first  11:00  26  130
5  C       last  22:00  37  240
6  D      first  15:00  30  170
7  D       last  15:00  30  170
```